# Por que al eliminar en un Array X elimina tambien en el Array A

Tags: javascript, array

Bueno estoy tratando eliminar un **item** de un `array` que es copia de otro , pero al momento de eliminarlo me elimina el **item** de los dos:

**Mi primer array**

```
ItemArrayUno = [{
0:
EsPeps: "2"
NumeroDocumento: "43254354325"
Participacion: "30"
RazonNombre: "Prueba"
TipoDocumento: {$id: "1", PTipo: 8000, Descripcion: "Cédula", Clase: 1, Action: null, …}
},
1:{
EsPeps: "2"
NumeroDocumento: "3131351351351"
Participacion: "20"
RazonNombre: "Prueba"
TipoDocumento: {$id: "1", PTipo: 8000, Descripcion: "Cédula", Clase: 1, Action: null, …}
}]
```

**El segundo seria algo así como la copia del primero y lo asigno así:**

```
 let ItemArrayDosCopia = [];

ItemArrayDosCopia = ItemArrayUno ;
```

Esto crea una "Copia del primero", y le realizo un **splice** a la copia ya que necesito conservar los datos primero, y lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
 ItemArrayDosCopia.splice(this.index, 1);
```

El **`this.index`** me llega como parámetro.

No entiendo por que me elimina del primero y del segundo si solo le estoy haciendo el **splice** a la copia me podrían ayudar a que solo elimine en la copia y el por que pasa esto ?

Comment: cuando haces a = b estas asignando la referencia  del objeto(en JavaScript el array es un objeto tambien pero con caracteristicas especiales)

Comment: copia el objeto de esta forma `Object.assign(ItemArrayDosCopia,ItemArrayUno)` tambien puedes hacer `ItemArrayDosCopia = ItemArrayUno.slice();` en ES6 es valido `ItemArrayUno = [...ItemArrayUno]`

Comment: Si lo hago de esa forma @JackNavaRow Al hacer el splice elimina todo , ya que eso realiza una copia superficial del array

Comment: es `slice` no `splice`

Comment: @JackNavaRow, me funciono perfecto con `Object.assign(ItemArrayDosCopia,ItemArrayUno)`quedo mejor de lo que esperaba , marque la respuesta del OS por que en el link tambien me explicaba como hacer lo que me dijiste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El fallo es que al hacer esta asignación no estás haciendo una copia, estás haciendo una referencia.

```
ItemArrayDosCopia = ItemArrayUno;
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es clonarlo:

```
ItemArrayDosCopia = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ItemArrayUno));
```

Una vez clonado cuando ejecutes esto:

```
 ItemArrayDosCopia.splice(this.index, 1);
```

ya no te modifcará ItemArrayUno

EDIT: He cambiado la solución porque solo funcionaba para casos muy sencillos. Como el array de la pregunta se componen de otros objetos más complejos hay que utilizar otros métodos. Como referencia deep cloning: https://dev.to/samanthaming/how-to-deep-clone-an-array-in-javascript-3cig

Comment: Gracias hermano , voy a probar.

Comment: el **splice** me limpia el primer **array** por completo ._. y la idea es conservar el **ArrayUno** con todos lo elementos

Comment: Si, perdón, la solución que puse solo funcionaba para casos muy básicos. He editado la respuesta a ver si con esto te valdría

Answer (score 1):

Es que en lugar de **splice** se debe usar **slice**

cito algo de la definición de cada una de las funciones.

> El método **splice()** cambia el contenido de un array eliminando
>   elementos existentes y/o agregando nuevos elementos.
>
> El método **slice()** devuelve una copia de una parte del array dentro de
>   un nuevo array empezando por inicio hasta fin (fin no incluido). El
>   array original no se modificará.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] te invito a hacer el [tour] asi podra ganar algunas medallas!